# Clearing a char-array

Tags: c

I want to clear some bits of a char array in c!
I wanted to know if it's faster to clear 4 bits (for example) this way :

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
array[2][i][9][14][1] = 0;
array[2][i][8][14][1] = 0;
array[2][i][7][14][1] = 0;
}
```

or by clearing the whole array by using

```
memset(&array[0], 0, sizeof(array));
```

the array is initialized by

```
unsigned char data[2][3][10][30][2];
```

Comment: Did I actually see a 5-D array? No offense, time to refactor the code.

Comment: That's an interesting array to say the least

Comment: Test it yourself using the `time` class at start and end, then calculate the difference

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know of some 2000+ Dimension arrays used in computer intelligence

Comment: Where are the "bits"? I only see bytes.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but you're comparing clearing 3 elements with clearing the whole thing. One does not benchmark apples vs oranges. You're not working on contiguous memory in the first snippet.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you are _actually_ trying to do. Also read [this](http://xyproblem.info/). And maybe you are mixing up "bits" and "bytes", that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: The loop clears 4*3=12 bytes. The memset() clears all of 3600 bytes. But the question asks for the faster method for clearing 4 bits. Which is it?

Comment: This isn't uncommon when simulating an object with exactly 5 degrees of freedom. @SouravGhosh No need for redesign in term of dimensions then.

Comment: @alk Right, just saying, that's not very common and we don;t get to see them _everyday_ :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Temperature, humidity and location are five already and being common to all of us! ;-)

Comment: guess i got my answer. thanks.
ps.: its an output array for a led-cube which has 3 dimensions, 3 brightnesses(so if its at max brightness the output data is in all 3 of them, if its at the lowest brightness its only in one of em) and 2 data-arrays ( one which is being written in and one which is being output)

Answer (score -2):

It depends from code optimalization during compilation.
Every compilator using different optimalization. (gcc / ms visual studio / etc ... )

I think nobody compile without optimalization nowadays.

Best way to compare which method is faster is make your own benchmark.

Try every method on really big data. Log timediff before cleaning and after cleaning for every method and use fastest.

I think memset is fastest. Just try.

Comment: This would have suited as comment.